# How to create application pages in Pages folder by using Visual Studio?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, application-pages

I tried to create an application page in SharePoint 2013 by using Visual Studio, The page was created but, I don't know where it's created in SharePoint?

And I need to create it in Sub-site Pages library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application pages get created in Layout folder 15 hive.

Following is the path of Layout folder

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

If you want to create page in pages folder, you have to use module element.
Following is sample code.

```
 <Module Name="Name" Url="Pages"  Path="PathInSolution">
    <File Url="Name.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary"  IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE"  Path="Name.aspx" Level="Published"  ReplaceContent="TRUE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay,Its working, great,Then i need to add pages into pages folder in sub site?

Comment: How to deploy the pages in sub site pages folder?@Akshay

Comment: Create one feature with web scope and add module element with above code.And activate this feature in the particulate sub site.you will find that feature under "manage site feature"

Comment: I tried to activate the feature, its shows a error message"Server Error in '/' Application."@Akshay

Comment: Do you have pages library in sub site?if not you need to activate "SharePoint server publishing feature" first.Could you please share your element.xml code?

Comment: Ya I have Pages Library in sub site. My xml code is                                                                                                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Layouts" Url="Pages">
    <File Path="Layouts\Finance.aspx" Url="Finance.aspx"  Type="GhostableInLibrary"  IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" Level="Published"  ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>

Comment: Feature is activated but still I can't found the pages in subsite pages folder @Akshay

Comment: Please refer this Link  https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/sharepoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module/

Comment: Can you share screen shot of solution explorer?